# What is it called when someone attacks a person and the offender gets an even worse reputation?

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests

What is it called when you defame someone and you happen to lose respect for doing that.

For example,

> "George is verbally attacking John, by doing that George is losing people's respect"

**Thus**:

> George <*blank*> himself by attacking John

Comment: A neat saying which encapsulates the phenomenon you describe is, "What goes around comes around."

Comment: "Backsplatter".

Comment: As a fill-in-the-blank word, _hurt_ works quite well in the example sentence you provide. More emphatically, _only hurt_ might convey the intended sense.

Comment: could be called a "blowback", but I don't know how to phrase it around your example.

Comment: This question reminded me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect

Comment: Side remark: You usually don't say "is losing people's respect"...

Comment: But Streisand effect is more like when the curiosity and interest of something is increased a lot as consequence of someone more and more desperately trying to hide/censor it.

Comment: In company where vulgarity is permitted, I'd substitute "f**ked" for "blank"

Comment: Bob totally "Hilaried" himself when he attacked Alice's thoughts on healthcare

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*George **[shot himself in the foot](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/shoot+in+the+foot)** by attacking John.*

> To do or say something that inadvertently undermines one's interests.

<sub>TFD</sub>

Comment: Oh yeah, now I remember it, I think this one fits it better, it's less formal, but it's more widely used +1

Comment: It's very common in Britain.

Comment: It's very common in the US too

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton Both literally and figuratively in both U.S. and Britain I'll assume. ;)

Comment: @DoubleDouble hey, what do you mean by literally? :)

Answer (score 43):

You could consider using the verb [**backfire**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/backfire) which means:

> (Of a plan or action) have an opposite and undesirable effect to what
>   was intended: '*overzealous publicity backfired on her*'.

Your example (You need to change the word order):

> George's attack on John backfired on himself.

[Oxford Online Dictionary]

Comment: This was on the tip of my tongue, but I couldn't remember it, common though it is. +1

Comment: @Charon Your suggestion seems to work better. :-)

Comment: Metaphoric discharge of firearms being the common theme!

Comment: Just don't say that someone "backfired himself in the foot".

Comment: "George's attack on John backfired" ....... ?

Comment: Quite similar: "backlash" or "blowback".

Answer (score 38):

George **undermined** himself by attacking John.

ie, 'mining' under what respect you have, causing your own self to 'fall'.

Comment: that fits it, and it's really formal

Comment: Because of the <blank> I thought you were looking for a one word answer...

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm looking for any expression that fits it, thanks for bringing a one-word answer + 1

Comment: This is the best one-word answer, although others would also fit:
"sabotaged himself"
"compromised himself"
"diminished himself (in the eyes of others)"

Answer (score 10):

George diminishes himself by attacking John.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a bit? Any references as to its usage you may have seen somewhere?

Comment: I've used it myself, and is OK linguistically - probably best to google 'diminish oneself' or 'diminish yourself' and you will get lots of examples.

Comment: Please do as Mark Norton suggests and expand on your answer.

Answer (score 8):

*George **scored an own-goal** by attacking John.*?

Comment: Most of the world needs no reference for this.  Bengals fan by any chance?

Comment: I've heard it phrased more as **scored on his own goal**.

Comment: **own-goal** is the term of art.  http://www.stltoday.com/sports/soccer/mls-likes-new-stadium-plans-here/article_904cb519-c8cd-5bf7-bde8-3de07fa37b36.html

Comment: @DanTheMan The idiom in Britain is the football one. A player who inadvertently puts the ball through his own goal, scores *an own goal*.

Comment: oh, this answer is too British, just kidding, thanks for the new idiom +1

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton Well if you want it in French, it is *un but contre son camp*, in German *ein Eigentor schießen*, in Italian and Spanish *un autogol*, and in Brazillian Portuguese *gol contra*. But the rules are the same everywhere thanks to that noble organisation FIFA!

Answer (score 2):

The problem with "[slinging mud](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/sling+mud+at)" or even getting into a "mudfight" with someone is that you'll often end up covered in the same mud. In fact, it's so very likely, that the concept is specifically stated in the definition example...

> **Casting aspersions with intent to discredit.**
>
> *The campaign degenerated into mutual mudslinging, each candidate trying to tarnish the other's reputation and looking bad in the
>   process.*

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mudslinging

Comment: Adlai Stevenson said, "He who slings mud generally loses ground."

Comment: @jejorda2 I like that quote. I've expanded it into [a full answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/301065/99085).

Answer (score 2):

There's an expression: **"Whoever slings mud, loses ground."**

It means that when you demean someone else, you demean yourself as well.

"Mudslinging" means insulting or attacking another person in order to harm his reputation or get him metaphorically dirty. "Losing ground" means falling behind in a competition, or being forced to move backwards. And it's also a play on words (mud/ground) -- when you throw something, you lose some of it.

So in this particular context, one might say **"George is slinging mud and losing ground."**

Comment: Similar proverbs: *You will reap what you sow". Or more familiar: "You fuck with the bull, you get the horns".

Answer (score 2):

"Debased" : lower the moral character of (someone).

George debased himself by attacking John

Comment: This is actually the best word for the purpose in question in the English language, as it explicitly conveys that verbally attacking another person makes one own self be considered base or crass, and thus automatically conveys the "George lost people's respect" part.

Comment: +1 I considered "defamed himself" which is apparently valid, and has a similar meaning, but I think "debased himself" is really what I was looking for (and is [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=defamed+himself%2Cdebased+himself)).

Answer (score 1):

It's a third party opinion. How about simply "George made a fool out of himself by attacking John".

Answer (score 1):

George was digging his own grave by attacking John.

Answer (score 1):

George is [cutting off his nose to spite his face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cutting_off_the_nose_to_spite_the_face) by attacking John.

> "Cutting off the nose to spite the face" is an expression used to describe a needlessly self-destructive over-reaction to a problem: "Don't cut off your nose to spite your face" is a warning against acting out of pique, **or against pursuing revenge in a way that would damage oneself more than the object of one's anger**.

Answer (score 0):

> If you attack him publicly on this, you'll only be **pissing into the
>   wind**.

Comment: This implies that the tide has already turned against anyone who would criticize the figure in question. I think the question is looking for a term that implies that the criticism itself will cause the tide to turn against the critic.

Comment: Not necessaily. Depends on how it's said.  Compare: "If *you* attack him publicly on this, ..."

Comment: Regardless, if the metaphorical "wind" is blowing, then an opposing force is there before the critic even opens their mouth.

Comment: There's always a wind blowing.

Comment: _Pissing into the wind_ is applying a feeble force against a substantial force. I don't think this captures the idea of your own actions rebounding against yourself.

Comment: This is more about futility than self sabotage.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan: But is there not a sense of futility in the OP's example, where an attempt to defame a person fails and only redounds to the attacker's discredit? One could even say "It's futile to attack him. It will only make you look bad."

Answer (score -1):

"Dishonored", "Defamed" and "Disgraced" all mean the same thing. Take your pick.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I'm looking for idioms "What is it called when you **defame** someone...""

Answer (score -2):

Petard
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petard
George made a petard of himself by attacking John.

Comment: Um, I think you mean that he hoisted himself with his own petard, not that he made himself a into petard.

Comment: "" "hoist with one's own petard", meaning: "to be harmed by one's own plan to harm someone else" "" made a petard of himself not made into a petard.

Comment: @Sam The one who is hoist with his own petard is the bomb _maker._ The petard is merely a bomb. Never the same thing.

Comment: @cobaltduck and David K: You two can word it however, you two choose to word it.  He asked for an idiom, I gave him an idiom “petard” with a link to the full idiom.  I used the word in the sentence as he asked.  I do not know how to fit the idiom into “George "hoist with one's own petard" himself by attacking John”, so I changed it to make it fit.  Yet it still fits all the other requirements he asked for.  I do not understand what your twos problems are!!!

Answer (score -2):

Degrades

I Know this is old post, but just in case someone else stumbles on this like I did

> degrades

seems to fit very well.